# Project 1 - how to come up with the boolean expression?

Tags: nand2tetris

I just started taking the course, and I have a general question.
In the first project we're required to build a few logic gates and I seem to have a problem with it.
I do understand how to write the hdl files and the syntax, but I'm having trouble realizing the gates' structures. With the simple gates like And and OR it's quite simple (especially with the given Nand gate), but with the more complex ones (like mux) I feel like I'm just shooting bullets in the air without a direction.
How am I supposed to come up with a correct implementation from the truth table?
Am I supposed to use dnf and then simplify the long expression? Cause I tried it to no avail (couldn't find a way to simplify it).

Sorry if it was a bit unclear but can someone please give me a pointer regarding how to "attack"
this sort of problems?

Thanks and have a great rest of week!

Answer (score 1):

You may find it helpful to think of things in terms of data flow.

For example, you can think of an AND gate as having a DATA-IN input, a CONTROL input, and a DATA-OUT output. DATA-IN only passes to DATA-OUT if CONTROL is 1, otherwise it is 0.

Similarly, an OR gate can be used to combine two inputs into a single output (as long as only one of them can ever be 1), and a NOT gate can be used to invert your sel control input so you now have two control signals, sel and notSel, only one of which will be 1.

So for a MUX, you need to create a circuit that lets the a signal "flow" through if sel is 0, and the b signal flow through if sel is 1, then weld the two flows together to form the out value. You should be able to do this using 4 gates.

If you need a further hint:

> Two AND gates, and one each NOT and OR.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to explain.
I do to some extent figured how the gates work, but I still don't understand how I'm supposed to come up with the correct circuit implementation.
In Mux for example (I know how to Implement it now), how you supposed to know what gates to use in order to achieve that result.

Comment: There is no one correct implementation, it’s more like there are trade offs between # of gates, ease of understanding, etc. For simple truth tables, you can just build circuits for each 1 output and then weld them together with ors. You can make them more efficient by exploiting commonalities, the same way you would simplify algebraic expressions. There are also tools that can convert a truth-table to a set of gates.

Comment: But once you get past about the complexity of the half-adder (ie: a few inputs and outputs), it becomes more like data flow programming.